# OS X App automatically remove copy, paste key equivalent in Edit menu

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, shortcut

In storyboard, I see key shortcuts in menu items

[image: storyboard]

But when I run app, this shortcuts remove automatically:

[image: app]

I do not understand why!

Comment: can't really understand your question, where do these menus come from?

Comment: @ithil when I enter text in NSTextView, I can't Select All, Copy or Paste with keyboard shortcut, only from menu.

Comment: You have probably assigned those shortcuts to another menu, possibly including a pop-menu in the window. If multiple menus have the same shortcuts assigned, it's arbitrary which will actually have it at run time.

Comment: @KenThomases, thank you! Yes, I used the wrong value keyEquivalent in NSMenuItem. I fix it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have evidently assigned those shortcuts to another menu item, possibly including a pop-menu in the window. If multiple menus have the same shortcuts assigned, it's arbitrary which will actually have it at run time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Those menus come from default template.
2. Your app in background calls validateMenuItem: If the menuItem can't perform action (e.g. copy:) the menuItem remains disabled.
3. object considered for validation is firstResponder (see below picture). If the firstResponder is nil -> menu item will be disabled. Your app in also checks if the object (firstResponder) responds to menu item selectors.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! but @KenThomases helped me

Comment: I missed that is about key shortcuts